# ClojureScript: migrating from fetch to shoreleave

Tags: clojure, fetch, clojurescript

As webnoir got deprecated I've decided to migrate from fetch as described in [docs](https://github.com/shoreleave/shoreleave-remote-ring), but for some reason shoreleave.remotes in not being compiled to Js and as a result I get

```
goog.require could not find: shoreleave.remotes.http_rpc
```

I've tried both remote-callback and remotes.macros. My ClojureScript namespace goes like this

```
(ns my.cljs.ns 
(:require [shoreleave.remotes.http-rpc :as rpc])
  (:require-macros [shoreleave.remotes.macros :as fm])
```

and backend

```
(ns my.backend
  (:use my.views
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]
        [compojure.handler :as handler]
        [cemerick.shoreleave.rpc :as rpc]))

 )

(rpc/defremote get-data [last-changed] 
  [:foo]
)

(defroutes my-routes
  (GET "/" [] (intro-view))
  (route/files "/" {:root "resources/public"})
  (route/not-found "<h1>Page not found</h1>"))


(def my-routing (-> #'my-routes
                   rpc/wrap-rpc
                   handler/site))
```

Any ideas how to get it working?

UPDATE: I found out that for some reason goog.require('shoreleave.remotes.http_rpc') goes before goog.provide('shoreleave.remotes.http_rpc')

Answer (score 1):

it was a problem with incremental complition in lein (see bug [CLJS-282](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-282)), adding ':incremental false' in project.clj fixed my problem:

```
:cljsbuild {
  :builds [{
    :incremental false
    :jar true
    :source-path "src-cljs"
    :compiler {
        :output-to "resources/public/js/js.js"
        :optimizations :whitespace
        :pretty-print true}
}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem by adding two dependencies in project.clj.

```
[shoreleave "0.3.0"]
[shoreleave/shoreleave-remote "0.3.0"]
```